# Laravel: how do I pass a value from a form to a controller?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I have a form:

```
{ Form::open(array('action' => 'RatesController@postUserRate', $client->id)) }}
    {{ Form::text('rate', '', array('placeholder' => 'Enter new custom client rate...')) }}
    {{ Form::submit('Submit', array('class' => 'btn btn-primary')) }}
{{ Form::close() }}
```

How do I pass my $client->id value through the form to my controller method?

I currently have a controller method that looks like this:

```
public function postUserRate($id)
{
    $currentUser = User::find(Sentry::getUser()->id);
    $userRate = DB::table('users_rates')->where('user_id', $currentUser->id)->where('client_id', $id)->pluck('rate');

    if(is_null($userRate))
    {
    ...
    }else{
    ....
    }
}
```

And the error log says "Missing argument 1 for RatesController::postUserRate()"

Any ideas on how to pass this $client->id into my controller so I can use it as I want to above?

Comment: you can create an hidden field in your form with the value `$client->id` and it will be submitted along with other fields

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Add `{{ Form::hidden('id', $client->id) }}`to the form. Then, when it's posted, you can fetch its value per usual with `Input::get('id')`.

Also, remove the `postUserRate` method's argument.

Comment: That's one solution, but what's gonna happen if an intruder intercepts the html form with tools like burp, and change the hidden value? If you know a solution about this, just let me know.

Answer (score 3):

You simply use :

`Form::open(array('action' => array('Controller@method', $user->id)))`

- the variable `$user->id` is passed as argument to the method `method`, also this last one should recieve an argument as well, like so :  `method($userId)`

Source : Laravel [documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/html#opening-a-form)